# Angular 2 async validator

Tags: angular

```
   isUnameTaken(formCtrl:FormControl): Promise<any>|Observable<any>{
    var status ;
    console.log(this.formGroup);

    this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/user/isAvaliable", { userName: formCtrl.value}).subscribe((resp:any)=>{
      console.log(resp);
       status = resp.status;
      console.log(status);
      if (status === 'success') {
        return Promise.resolve({ userExists: true });
      } else {
        return Promise.resolve(null);
      }
    });


  }
```

I am getting status as undefined because post request takes time to resolve I tried to work around using Promise.resolve to return promise
 so how to wait for the response in a proper way

Above function is angular validator function

Comment: Use the rxjs `map` function instead of `subscribe`. If it's rxjs 6, you'll need to use `map` in conjunction with `pipe`

Comment: can I ask you something my issue right now is that I want to wait for that status and based on that I want to return validation result . How will adding map and pipe solve this issue forgive my ignorance

Comment: Because pipe allows us to transform the value that's emitted by the `Observable`. That way, the caller can `subscribe` to the Observable, and wait for it to emit its value

Comment: Is there any example of this

Comment: Which version of RXJS are you using?

Comment: version is 6.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Observable`s `map` function to transform the value that's emitted by the `Observable`, like so:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...

return this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/user/isAvaliable", { userName: formCtrl.value }).pipe(
  map((resp: any) => {
    console.log(resp);
    status = resp.status;
    console.log(status);
    return status === 'success' ? { userExists: true } : null;
  })
);
```

Comment: thank you for helping but if I was using previous http module could the same thing be done ?? did it employ pipe and map for that same ?

Comment: Yes, you can use `.map` directly instead of `.pipe` and `.map` together